# Getting Segmentation Fault in C in a simple program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote a program which test the age of person , if the age is above 18 it further asks the name and gender of the person and depending on the gender it prints if output.

But after I enter the age I am getting Segmentation Fault error.

I am using debian and I am a beginner in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender;

    printf("How old are you ? \n");
    scanf(" %d",age);
    if(age >= 18){
        printf("What your name ? \n");
        scanf(" %s",&name);
        printf("What's your gender ? (m/f) \n");
        scanf(" %c",&gender);
        if(gender == 'm'){
            printf("Welcome Mr. %s \n",name);
        }else{
            printf("Welcome Ms/Mrs %s \n",name);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Nothing to see here! \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d",age);` ==> `scanf("%d", &age);`

Comment: `char name;` only holds one single character. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick I corrected that one as soon as I realised

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `&` in the line:

```
scanf(" %d",age);
```